# How come a child's "white-space: pre;" changes its parent's table "width"?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a `table` with `width: 500px`. Inside the table, I have a child that has `white-space: pre;`.

However, it seems like that combination makes that the table's 500px `width` is ignored.

It's hard to describe, so please check the demo.

https://jsfiddle.net/1fs4zxr2/4/

```css
table {
  width: 500px;
  background: blue;
}

.codeblock {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  max-width: 72%;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="codeblock">
        "/oauth2/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" + APP_REFRESH_TOKEN + "&client_id=" + APP_CLIENT_ID + "&client_secret=" + APP_CLIENT_SECRET,
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there anyway I can make the `codeblock` respect the table's 500px width?

Comment: you need 
    table-layout: fixed; on the table

Comment: Oh wow, this works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolute (i.e. `px`)  value for the `max-width` of the cell (BTW: having `width: 100%` and `max-width: 72%` is a contradiction). I used max-width 360px below, which is 72% (your previous max-width value) of the container's 500px:

```css
table {
  width: 500px;
  background: blue;
}

.codeblock {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  max-width: 360px;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>

      <div class="codeblock">
        "/oauth2/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" + APP_REFRESH_TOKEN + "&client_id=" + APP_CLIENT_ID + "&client_secret=" + APP_CLIENT_SECRET,
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. However, "codeblock " should be "width: 100%;" so it can be generally used regardless av parent. I don't want to hard code a px width on "codeblock".

Comment: Regarding "regardless of parent": In the question you wrote "I have a table with width: 500px".... You can still add `width: 100%` additionally - try it...